# Error Accessing Files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have copied some files into hdfs and would like to verify that they are, in fact, there. When I ran the command `hadoop fs -ls` before, I was able to see all existing directories in hdfs. However, now I am getting the error: `ls: '.': No such file or directory`

How  can I access files in hdfs?

Comment: update: I tried `hadoop fs -ls /` and was able to get this result: `0 2014-07-16 20:10 /tmp`. However, I don't see the input and output directories that I saw when I last checked hdfs. Am I supposed to copy files into hdfs again when I re-start hadoop?

Comment: Are you expecting more directories and files under the root directory? If so, check that all datanodes are up and running. You should run `hadoop dfsadmin -report`.

Comment: I believe all the datanodes are running correctly. Also, I created a directory called /user/[my username] using `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/[username]` and I am not getting any more errors. Looks like it was because I didn't have a home directory. Thanks for the advice anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

hadoop fs -ls /dirname